# Android: Handle headset buttons events and Send information to MainActivity

Tags: android, headset

Here's my effort to make a working code to handle a headset button event the best way. I read the [Android developer guide](https://developer.android.com/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html), but it is obviously wrong  because they ask to start listening registering a class name.

```
am.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(RemoteControlReceiver); // Wrong
```

So I check out other examples to correct the code. For example many secret suggestions have been published in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10177417/broadcastreceiver-for-action-media-button-not-working/29517224#29517224), I also tried other code such as [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36172380/detect-headset-buttons-double-click-and-long-pressclick-android), and another solution with [MediaSession](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39410268/how-to-listen-to-action-down-key-pressed-event-in-android-onmediabuttonevent/39413753#39413753), and cleaning the unneeded I wrote this code:

I implemented the class *RemoteControlReceiver*. Apparently there is no need for a static inner class, in fact, see [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13257982/mediabuttonintentreceiver-not-working-in-android-4-0#comment21211299_13576130):

```
public class RemoteControlReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

        public RemoteControlReceiver() {
            super();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            Toast.makeText(context, "EVENT!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
                if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY == event.getKeyCode()) {
                    Toast.makeText(context, "EVENT!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Then I registered the intent inside the *MainActivity onCreate(){*...

```
    AudioManager am = (AudioManager) this.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
    ComponentName mReceiverComponent = new ComponentName(this, RemoteControlReceiver.class);
    am.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(mReceiverComponent);
```

The registerMediaButtonEventReceiver is deprecated by the way...

Inside the manifest I recorder the filter, after the activity tag:

```
<activity>
...
</activity>

<receiver android:name=".RemoteControlReceiver" android:enabled="true">
    <intent-filter android:priority="2147483647">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Note: with a static inner class would be, e.g., "*.MainActivity$RemoteControlReceiver*".

I am working on

```
compileSdkVersion 24
buildToolsVersion "24.0.0"
...
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 24
```

Here my questions:

- Why the *registerMediaButtonEventReceiver* is deprecated? Seems all this paradigm is wrong nowadays, but I found no information on how to handle these class of problems on the Android Developer Portal.
- Which way may I interact with the MainActivity? My purpose is to perform an action on the MainActivity when some headset operation has been performed.

Comment: Your manifest says `MainActivity$MediaButtonReceiver` but your class is called `RemoteControlReceiver`. Which is it?

Comment: Thank you @ianhanniballake for niticing that. It was just a copy paste typo though, I have implemented many receivers during all the experiments. Now I corrected it, I confir the setup is as described.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

API 21 changed the entire media app APIs, now centering entirely around [MediaSession](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSession.html). Instead of registering a `BroadcastReceiver` (as was needed prior to API 18) or a `PendingIntent` (via [registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(PendingIntent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(android.app.PendingIntent))), you can receive callbacks directly in the [MediaSession.Callback](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/session/MediaSession.Callback.html).

You can set up a `MediaSession` via the following code:

```
MediaSession.Callback callback = new MediaSession.Callback() {
  @Override
  public void onPlay() {
    // Handle the play button
  }
};
MediaSession mediaSession = new MediaSession(context,
  TAG); // Debugging tag, any string
mediaSession.setFlags(
  MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_MEDIA_BUTTONS |
  MediaSession.FLAG_HANDLES_TRANSPORT_CONTROLS);
mediaSession.setCallback(callback);

// Set up what actions you support and the state of your player
mediaSession.setState(
  new PlaybackState.Builder()
    .setActions(PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY |
                PlaybackState.ACTION_PAUSE |
                PlaybackState.ACTION_PLAY_PAUSE);
    .setState(PlaybackState.STATE_PLAYING,
      0, // playback position in milliseconds
      1.0); // playback speed

// Call this when you start playback after receiving audio focus
mediaSession.setActive(true);
```

If you only want to handle media buttons while your activity is visible, you can just have your `MediaSession` handled by the Activity itself (this would allow your `Callback` to just be a variable in your Activity).

The [Best practices in media playback talk from I/O 2016](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iIKxyDRjecU) goes through all of the details and other APIs required to build a great media app, although note that it uses [MediaSessionCompat](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/media/session/MediaSessionCompat.html) and the other Support Library classes as detailed in the [Media playback and the Support Library blog post](https://medium.com/google-developers/meida-playback-and-the-must-have-android-support-library-apis-9f48dc6b657e).

Comment: That's it @ianhanniballake, I wanted to find information about the new best practices. All the attached references will also be useful. Thank you!

Comment: @ianhanniballake, what if i just want to listen to buttons events, without playing any media. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: i'm also looking for a way to listen to button presses without actually playing media. (only while app visible).

Comment: tried the sample code from Ian and it works now. seems that i had wrong order of mediaSession setup. (setting state before setActive seems to be crucial)

Comment: Hi! On my phone triple press on headset started to be responded to as double + single in an 3rd party app (app not changed when behavior changed). Do you know if triple is single event or 3 separate events? I want to understand better before maybe making a bug report. TIA